# Set root pages directory in nuxt based on domain

Tags: routes, nuxt.js

Im going to create a whitelabel project with Nuxt.

Let's say i have two domains, domainA.com and domainB.com and a pages-directory like:

```
- pages
    - domainA
        - index.vue
        ...
    - domainB
        - index.vue
        - about.vue
        ...
```

How can I set the root routing directory on app start based on the domain?

For example:

```
https://domainA.com -> pages/domainA/index.vue
https://domainB.com/about -> pages/domainB/about.vue
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can!

There is a good [article](https://nubisoft.io/blog/how-to-multiple-subdomains-nuxt-js/) that clarify all process and have code example, but you need to install @nuxtjs/router, because built-in file system routing won`t fit